# What is the safest wrist angle for pushing exercises?

Tags: weightlifting, wrist, safety

When doing push exercises, such as the bench press and military press, what is should the angle of the wrist be to prevent injury? Should the wrist be straight or should it be bent like the following image?

[image]

Comment: You don't want to bend your wrists back you want to keep them in a straight neutral position

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for exactly. Have you had trouble in the past with your wrist or are you just looking for general guidelines?

Comment: I have wrist pain doing clean-and-presses. One wrist always becomes sore after a few reps. I'm wondering if it's the wrist angle that's causing my pain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article about [biomechanical explanation](https://www.ptonthenet.com/articles/biomechanics-of-the-bench-press-4019) of bench press with references at the end.
To make the long story short; 
Grasp the barbell with an opposing thumb grip (thumbs wraps around the bar) with your hands shoulder-width or slightly wider than shoulder-width apart.
An opposing thumb grip provides more security and control of the barbell.
**Grasp the bar with the wrists positioned directly under the bar. This position helps avoid hyperextension of the wrists.**
Retract your shoulder blades (scapulae), bringing them closer together.